# How can I get a priest villager to get gold trade?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried several times in creative to get the Priest type villager to have a trade gold, Gold -> Emerald. My goal is to have a villager in SMP that does gold as the last trade. But even though the sheet on the wiki says that Priest type can get gold trade as a common trade I've yet to see it.

The disclaimer is that it can, but only if it cant do other trades? I'm not really sure. So that's what confuses me about it. I'm hoping eventually if i trade the last trade long enough gold will pop up, but i have no idea. Do they actually get it or not?

Any insight or answers would be appreciated.

This is the source I'm using https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading

Answer (score 1):

The exact mechanics of how a villager generates their next trade are, from the link you posted:

> The game first compiles a list of potential offers, and the probability is used to determine whether the offer is included in this list. Then one offer is selected from this list at random to be the actual new offer generated.

So basically, every trade that a villager legitimately has in their list of possible trades, has a chance to go on the list. After the list is built, a single item is chosen from among those that made it onto it, and the chosen item is the villager's new trade. There is always, however, the chance that a villager will generate a new trade, and the list will be empty; when this happens, the villager gets the Gold Purchase trade you're after.

For some types of villagers, this is really unlikely, but priests have a fairly good chance of it, because they only have a dozen possible trades, every one of which is more likely to be off the list than on.

Comment: Ive gotten to the last trade on 3 priest type villagers without any type of gold trade yet. On one of them ive traded the last trade 50+ times so either its extremely bad luck or they are unable to naturally get gold trades. Except for maybe when they first spawn. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is no 'last trade'. Every time you use the last trade listed, then exit the trading window, the villager will generate a new trade. It might be a duplicate of one they already have, or similar, but with a differing cost, but it will always happen. Keep using the last trade on the list, and the gold should eventually come up.

Comment: Thats incorrect. They will look like they are generating a new trade but once they have all their trades listed they no longer gain any new trades. The last trade they have, say paper on a librarian for example, will never go away as the last trade. Basically allowing you to trade paper an unlimited number of times because it never changes. Also the cost of the trade never changes as well. But since my priests have 1 last trade they can learn, which is supposed to be gold, they should have some type of chance at it according to wiki. But i've yet to see it except on a newly spawned villager.

Comment: Thank you for the comments though. im gonna keep trying that trade until i feel like hes just not going to give gold in that last trade slot. Im not sure if it even can except on a Blacksmith.

Comment: Trust me, what I've described is how it works. Every time you use that last trade, they're generating a new trade. It's just replacing what's there. If, e.g., they generate the "Sell Redstone" trade, and that priest already has "Sell Redstone", the newly chosen price will just replace the old one. And, if you absolutely refuse to believe me, just use the first few trades over and over. After using it some amount (between 3 and 13 times), the trade will be removed from their list, until the next time it's generated.